# RabbitMQ multiple acknowledges to same message closes the consumer

Tags: go, rabbitmq

If I acknowledge the same message twice using the [Delivery.Ack](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Delivery.Ack) method, my consumer channel just closes by itself.

Is this expected behaviour? Has anyone experienced this ?

The reason I am acknowledging the same message twice is a special case where I have to break the original message into copies and process them on the consumer. Once the consumer processes everything, it loops and acks everything. Since there are copies of the entity, it acks the same message twice and my consumer channel shuts down

Comment: It seems to me it is an expected behavior, but i cant find any proof :-).

Comment: Yeah..I tried to look for proof but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [AMQP reference](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.ack), a channel exception is raised when a message gets acknowledged for the second time:

> A message MUST not be acknowledged more than once. The receiving peer
>   MUST validate that a non-zero delivery-tag refers to a delivered
>   message, and raise a channel exception if this is not the case.

Second call to `Ack(...)` for the same message will not return an error, but the channel gets closed due to this exception received from server:

```
Exception (406) Reason: "PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag ?"
```

It is possible to register a listener via [Channel.NotifyClose](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.NotifyClose) to observe this exception.